# How to edit the wordpress' blog collection page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to edit the wordpress' blog page's layout but cannot do so, I tried to implement a new layout to represent the collection blogs in one single page

am i missing some plugins here or something else? I am new to the wordpress

I tried various options to edit the blog collection page's layout but no success yet. and one more thing if the blog is added through the siteorigin editor it is showing in the parent list of the blog and but if it is added through some other page builder it is not showing in the parent list of the blogs.